# using perl with emacs editor

Tags: perl, emacs

I am new to perl and emacs and want to work with perl on the emacs editor

How can I add perl mode to emacs23 or configure it to work with perl more friendly ?

Comment: Emacs 23 includes a perl-mode by default. If you visit a .pl file, it will use it.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget that [www.emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org) is a gold mine ! There's a page on http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PerlLanguage

I think that the auto completion for the perl language is nice :
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PerlCompletion ; There's a vimeo screencast about the auto completion with perl and emacs here: http://vimeo.com/4739908

In addition, I think that you should use [PDE](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PerlDevelopEnvironment) :

> Emacs::PDE is a collection of Emacs Lisp extensions to facilitate Perl programming. CPerl Mode has provided an excellent environment for coding; Emacs::PDE provides other common tools such as creating files using templates, smart compiling, perldoc, perltidy, debugger, tags tree view and so on. PDE also provides an easy configuration for Perl programing, and a tutorial for novices to start using Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

There are detailed instructions [on the emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPerlMode)